# python3 unicode-escape doesn't  work with non-ascii bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python2, there is `string-escape` and `unicode-escape`. For utf-8 byte string, string-escape could escape \ and keep non-ascii bytes, like:

```
"你好\\n".decode('string-escape')
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\n'
```

However, in python3, `string-escape` is removed. We have to encode string into bytes and decode it with `unicode-escape`:

```
"This\\n".encode('utf_8').decode('unicode_escape')
'This\n'
```

It does work with ascii bytes. But non-ascii bytes will also be escaped:

```
"你好\\n".encode('utf_8')
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\\n'
"你好\\n".encode('utf_8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf_8')
b'\xc3\xa4\xc2\xbd\xc2\xa0\xc3\xa5\xc2\xa5\xc2\xbd\n'
```

All non-ascii bytes are escaped, which leads to encoding error.

So is there a solution for this ? Is it possible in python3 to keep all non-ascii bytes and decode all escape chars ?

Answer (score 5):

```
import codecs
codecs.getdecoder('unicode_escape')('你好\\n')
```

Comment: This does not work; the decoder will implicitly encode the string to UTF-8 before applying the decoding, and then the decoding translates the UTF-8 bytes into individual characters. I get `('ä½\xa0å¥½\n', 8)` from the above code.

Comment: huh, you're right. that no longer works now. I'm not sure what changed. I also can't find a solution that works now. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/65530 seems to explain the issue but not when it broke. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48908131/385891 is only valid for ASCII now (I think)