# decode(unicode_escape) in python 3 a string

Tags: python, escaping

I've checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3) but it doesn't work in python3.

I've an escaped string of this kind: `str = "Hello\\nWorld"` and I want to obtain the same string unescaped: `str_out = Hello\nWorld`

I tried with this without succes: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Here my sample code:

```
str = "Hello\\nWorld"
str.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`decode` applies to `bytes`, which you can create by encoding from your string.

I would encode (using default) *then* decode with `unicode-escape`

```
>>> s = "Hello\\nWorld"
>>> s.encode()
b'Hello\\nWorld'
>>> s.encode().decode("unicode-escape")
'Hello\nWorld'
>>> print(s.encode().decode("unicode-escape"))
Hello
World
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't cut it when your string contains non-ascii characters. Encoding to `latin1` in the interim seems to work though, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829514/791713.