# "Unescaping" backslashes in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, pyyaml

TL;DR;

I want to transform a string (representing a regex) like `"\\."` into `"\."` in a clean and resilient way (something akin to `sed 's/\\\\/\\/g'`, I don't know if this could break on edge cases though) 
`val.decode('string-escape')` is not an option since I'm using python3.

What I tried so far:

- variations of `val.replace('\\\\', '\\')`
- looked at the answers to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908131/decodeunicode-escape-in-python-3-a-string) 
  questions but couldn't get them to work in my case

  - variations of `val.encode().decode('unicode-escape')`
- had a look at the [docs for strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) but 
  couldn't find a solution

I am sure that I missed a relevant part, because string escaping (and unescaping) seems like a fairly common and basic problem, but I haven't found a solution yet =/

Full Story:

I have a YAML-File like so

```yaml
- !Scheme
      barcode: _([ACGTacgt]+)[_.]
      lane: _L(\d\d\d)[_.]
      name: RKI
      read: _R(\d)+[_.]
      sample_name: ^(.+)(?:_.+){5}
      set: _S(\d+)[_.]
      user: _U([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)[_.]
      validation: .*/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+_)+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9])+\.fastq.*
...
```

that describes a "Scheme" Object. 
The 'name' key is an identifier and the rest describe regexes.

I want to be able to parse an object from that YAML so I wrote a `from_yaml` class method:

```py
scheme = Scheme()
loaded_mapping = loader.construct_mapping(node)  # load yaml-node as dictionary WARNING! loads str escaped

# re.compile all keys except name, adding name as regular string and
# unescaping escaped sequences (like '\') in the process
for key, val in loaded_mapping.items():
    if key == 'name':
        processed_val = val
    else:
        processed_val = re.compile(val)  # backslashes in val are escaped
    scheme.__dict__[key] = processed_val
```

the problem is that `loader.construct_mapping(node)` loads the strings with backslashes escaped, so the regex is not correct anymore.

I tried several variations of `val.encode().decode('unicode-escape')` and `val.replace('\\\\', '\\')`,
but had no luck with it

If anyone has an idea how to handle this I'd appreciate it very much! I am not married to this specific way of doing things and open to alternative approaches.

Kind Regards!

Comment: The question is unclear. When you have a string literal `"\\."` then this **is** the string `\.`. What do you mean by "represent"?

Comment: by "represent" I mean that this should ultimately get `re.compile()`ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have this super simple YAML file

```
lane: _L(\d\d\d)[_.]
```

and load it with PyYAML like this:

```
import yaml
import re

with open('test.yaml', 'rb') as stream:
    data = yaml.safe_load(stream)

lane_pattern = data['lane']
print(lane_pattern)

lane_expr = re.compile(data['lane'])
print(lane_expr)
```

Then the result is exactly as one would expect:

```
_L(\d\d\d)[_.]
re.compile('_L(\\d\\d\\d)[_.]')
```

There is no double escaping of strings going on when YAML is parsed, so there is nothing for you to unescape.

Comment: my bad you're right, I just messed up the actual regex! thanks for your trouble ^^'

Comment: @Fynn I thought so, but suspected that some code you did not write might be responsible, hence the minimum attempt to reproduce.